# Can a macro insert instruction after clearing cell data?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that contains several cells that instruct the user what to write in each cell.  In order to do this, the user deletes the instruction after reading it and inputs data.  They then hit a macro button which saves and clears data.  My problem is I want the instruction to be there for the next user and not a blank cell.

Here's what I have:

```
Sub NEXTINVOICE()
    Range("C7").value = Range("C7").value + 1
    Range("A13:A13, A16:C42, C9:D9").ClearContents
    Sheets("PROCESS SHEET").Range("B7:C9, A15:G67, B71:B75, G84:G204").ClearContents
    Sheets("PROCESS SHEET (2)").Range("B7:C9, A15:G67, B71:B75, G84:G204").ClearContents
    Sheets("PROCESS SHEET (3)").Range("B7:C9, A15:G67, B71:B75, G84:G204").ClearContents
    Sheets("PROCESS SHEET (4)").Range("B7:C9, A15:G67, B71:B75, G84:G204").ClearContents
    Sheets("PROCESS SHEET (5)").Range("B7:C9, A15:G67, B71:B75, G84:G204").ClearContents
    Sheets("DOOR & LINER PRICES").Range("B18:B105, B123:B211, B228:B243, B247:B251, B256:B264").ClearContents
    Sheets("TIMBER CALCULATOR").Range("A5:A5, A8:A8, A12:B12, A16:B16, A23:B23, E12:E12, E16:E16, E23:E23").ClearContents
End Sub

Sub SaveInvWithNewName()
    Dim NewFN As Variant
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy
    NewFN = "\\NASDE8FB1\MCM Cloud\Estimating\Quote Numbers\QUOTE_MR_" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QUOTE SHEET").Range("C7").value & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewFN, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    NEXTINVOICE
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are the instructions saved?

Comment: The instruction is in the cell.  The user reads the instruction, deletes it. then types the answer in the same cell.  When they save and clear I want to put the instruction back in the cell before it saves, for the next user

Comment: You should recopy them from some safe place, i.e. some hidden worksheet.

Comment: What would the code be for this? I'm an amateur when it comes to code.  I have had help with the code above.  Could you insert the line of code into my example above?